# Different Layout/html structures for different pages in angular 8 Not working

Tags: angular

I've tried to create a public routes and secure routes, each with different html structures (secure routes will have a dashboard feel/look while public routes have a more marketing type structure), but the routing isn't working. I have a feeling I have too many `<router-outlets>` but I'm not 100% sure.

My AppRoutingModule looks like this:

```js
    const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'request-demo', component: RequestDemoComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];

    const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ] },
      { path: 'u',
        canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ],
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: UserDetailComponent,
            resolve: { user: UserDetailResolver },
            pathMatch: 'full',
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', component: PublicLayoutComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
      { path: '', component: SecureLayoutComponent, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

public-layout.component.html is:

```html
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and secure-layout.component.html is:

```html
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My login service should take you from the public-layout to the secure layout via this router (using Router) on successful login.

```js
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
```

But on login, this doesn't seem to work as I'm still on '/' and not dashboard and in console, inspecting the elements, `<app-public-layout>` is what's being displayed.

[image]

Updated with login.component.ts login function:

```js
    login() {
        if (this.authService.login(this.loginModel)) {
          this.loginModel.email = "";
          this.loginModel.password = "";
          console.log(
            "Welcome back " + this.authService.currentUser.firstName
          );
          this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Email and/or password is incorrect. Please try again."
          );
          this.loginModel = {
            email: "",
            password: ""
          };
        }
      }

login function in auth service (using local user array for dev):

    login(userEmail: IUserLogin): boolean {
        const userExists = this.users.USERS.find(x => x.email === userEmail.email);
        if (userExists) {
          this.currentUser = userExists;
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userExists));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

loggedin guard:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {

        constructor(protected router: Router, protected auth: AuthService ) {}

         canActivate() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
                return true;
            }
            // not logged in so redirect to login page
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So your problem is that when you login, the login service should redirect to `/dashboard`, but it stays on `/`? Even though you have a redirect on `''`? Can you show the relevant code from `LoginService` and `LoggedInGuard`.

Comment: updated the main thread with auth service login functions and login guard

Comment: I removed the LoggedInGuard to take it out of the equation and it's still redirecting to '/' after successful login and not showing /dashboard or dashboard html structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how your routing is configured.

Boiling it down to the problem routes leaves the following configuration:

```js
const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ] }
];

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: PublicLayoutComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
  { path: '', component: SecureLayoutComponent, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];
```

When the url is `/`, there are currently 3 top-level routes the router will try to match.

It should be remembered that the order routes are declared in is important. The router will check them in order.

1. `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }`

One problem in your example is that the route `'home'` doesn't exist.

At the moment `/home` doesn't exist, so the router will fallback to the next route...

2. `{ path: '', component: PublicLayoutComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES }`

The router will match against the first child, where it finds another `redirectTo: 'home'`. This will then fall back to the `'**'` path, which redirects to `''`. This is now a cyclical path. I suspect the router recognises this and stays at the url `/`. It will render the `PublicLayoutComponent` without anything to put in `<router-outlet>`.

3. `{ path: '', component: SecureLayoutComponent, children: SECURE_ROUTES }`

The router hasn't even attempted to match against this path.

#### The fix

The '**' should be moved out of the child routes and into the top-level routes.

The top-level routes should be declared in order of most-specific to most-general.

The `LoggedInGuard` should be moved to the top-level route to save you redeclaring it on every child route.

You will also need to ensure you add the `'home'` route.

```js
const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PublicLayoutComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
  { path: '', component: SecureLayoutComponent, children: SECURE_ROUTES, canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzqvcr

Disclaimer: I've not gone through the source code of the router. So I can't claim to know for certain how it resolves circular routes. My answer is based on my observations in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to put the  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in both the components.
Remove the router tag from both components and put the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the parent component, like, *app.component.ts* and use public component route as default route if not logged in.

Comment: If I take out router-outlet from public-layout.html and secure-layout.html and only have it in app.component.html, then none of my routes work

Comment: What makes you say there are too many `<router-outlet>` elements? This is how you set up layout components.

Comment: @KurtHamilton, yeah I thought so :) but it's not working so I'm struggling to discover why the dashboard isn't showing up after I login.